# Prompt for user group when logging into OSX domain

Tags: mac-osx-server, opendirectory

When a user is a member of more than one group, when logging in to a 10.6 machine, it shows a prompt asking for what group to apply settings for.

We're using the groups to mount different shares, e.g. `Production` and `Accounts`, based on user membership.  Often, a user is a member of more than one group, and needs all the drives available.

The Open Directory server is running 10.6 also.

Is there a way to skip this prompt and apply settings for all groups.  I can foresee that there may be conflicts between group settings, but perhaps a priority can be set too?
Or is this totally the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: I remember trying to find a solution for this long ago, and gave up! Sorry!

Comment: Back in the days of Panther, there used to be a checkbox on the screen that would pop up to select the groups. I take it that is now gone?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a login script to map the drives that they need.  It works really well if you use the `groups` command and just check for the correct AD group membership.

I just looked for it but I must have deleted it when we switched to our single NAS.  Sorry.

If you don't like that option I experimented with using groups that combine the settings (Production, Accounting, ProductionAndAccounting, etc.).  This gets really complicated if you have a large number of combinations but it worked at a small scale. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no priority to be set, from what I know.

Plus, at least when I had an issue like this on Tiger, it would ask if you wanted to remember this, or save that group, like in a check box when you select it each time, which should keep that from coming up in the future....